# What is a German potato grater called?

Tags: equipment, potatoes

I know of this grater via German cooking, but it may NOT be specific to Germany.  Regardless, I am trying to determine the name of this kind of grater so I can purchase one.  The grater is actually raised up on the side you rub the potato on, exactly like I have nutmeg graters.

Here are some pictures.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me the name of tis grater?  Bonus if you can point me to a website that sells them.

Thanks

Comment: They used to refer to this style of grater as a 'rasp', but these days when you search for that, you also find the 'microplane' type graters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curved grater - [there ya go](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00062BE16).

Answer (score 6):

Kartoffelreibe
Is the German name for it I just try to find one to  buy but they on ebay and the shipping is unexplainable high, for the Kartoffelreibe about 10 they charge 80 for shipping. Would settle for a used one.